# Python Help : Colouring and Bold

Tags: python, text-styling

I have tried changing the this " to this ' getting rid of the brackets and much more but it doesn't want to work
This is the code I have:

```
print("\033[1m" + 'Here are some commands you can do:" + "\033[0m")
```

this is the output

```
[1mHere are some commands you can do:[0m
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: This have a syntax error as I see one `'`

Comment: I have fixed it and it now looks like this but it still doesn't work

Comment: print("\033[1m" + "Here are some commands you can do:" + "\033[0m")

Comment: In what environment are you running this code?  That looks like it would work from a terminal, but probably not from within an IDE or other GUI environment.

Comment: yeah i realised that it doesn't work with idle now. Thanks

Comment: That's just for the linux terminal, it does not work for idle.